# Running out of PermGen space in Tomcat when running multiple Tridion CD instances

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, java

On my dev environments I am running multiple instances of Tridion Content Delivery in the same Tomcat (JVM) server. Typically I have:

- 2x Tridion Deployer
- 1x OData Web Service
- 2 or 4x Tridion Content Delivery (websites)

By the time the 3rd or 4th instance of Tridion starts I start getting Permgen space errors. My server has enough memory available, how can I increase the amount of memory used by Tomcat?

Comment: I think even as per the FAQ this is very much desirable to ask question to which you know answer and come across multiple options. +1 for sharing nice question (and answer (by Eric))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is by updating the Catalina.bat file to increase the Heap Size in the java ops.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: I was going to answer that you can add this to the Tomcat startup options (pretty much the same you're saying with Catalina.bat). Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to see what options were originally used?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to set these parameters is creating a file called setenv.bat (Windows) or setenv.sh (Linux) and place it in the Tomcat bin directory. you can put here the variables JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS, I prefer setting CATALINA_OPTS because these varaible affects only Tomcat, not for other Java applications.

**set CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m** -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" (windows)

**export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m** -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" (Linux)

Hope this hepls